# How to write in a proper way to skip copy the empty rows from this form? Thanks!

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

```
function ClearCellRegistroMovimientos() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formS = ss.getSheetByName("Registro de Movimientos");

  var RangeToClear = [ "F7", "C12", "D12", "F12", "G12", "c15", "d15",  
  "f15", "g15", "c16",  "d16",  "f16",  "g16", "c17",   "d17",  "f17",
  "g17", "c18", "d18",  "f18",  "g18", "c19",   "d19",  "f19",  "g19",
  "c20", "d20", "f20",  "g20", "c21",   "d21",  "f21",  "g21", "c22",   
  "d22", "f22", "g22", "c23",   "d23",  "f23",  "g23"];

   for (var i=0; i<RangeToClear.length; i++) { 
    formS.getRange(RangeToClear[i]).clearContent();
    }
  }

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  function SubmitDataRegistroMovimientos() {
    var ss    = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var formS = ss.getSheetByName("Registro de Movimientos");
    var dataS = ss.getSheetByName("REGISTRO STOCK");
    
    var values = [[formS.getRange("F7").getValue(),
                   formS.getRange("c12").getValue(),
                   formS.getRange("d12").getValue(),
                   formS.getRange("F12").getValue(),
                   formS.getRange("G12").getValue(),
                   formS.getRange("C15").getValue(),
                   formS.getRange("D15").getValue(),
                   formS.getRange("E15").getValue(),
                   formS.getRange("F15").getValue(),
                   formS.getRange("G15").getValue()]]
   dataS.getRange(dataS.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, 10).setValues(values);


    var values = [[formS.getRange("F7").getValue(),
                   formS.getRange("c12").getValue(),
                   formS.getRange("d12").getValue(),
                   formS.getRange("F12").getValue(),
                   formS.getRange("G12").getValue(),
                   formS.getRange("C16").getValue(),
                   formS.getRange("D16").getValue(),
                   formS.getRange("E16").getValue(),
                   formS.getRange("F16").getValue(),
                   formS.getRange("G16").getValue()]]
   dataS.getRange(dataS.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, 10).setValues(values);

   
   var values = [[formS.getRange("F7").getValue(),
                   formS.getRange("c12").getValue(),
                   formS.getRange("d12").getValue(),
                   formS.getRange("F12").getValue(),
                   formS.getRange("G12").getValue(),
                   formS.getRange("C17").getValue(),
                   formS.getRange("D17").getValue(),
                   formS.getRange("E17").getValue(),
                   formS.getRange("F17").getValue(),
                   formS.getRange("G17").getValue()]]
   dataS.getRange(dataS.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, 10).setValues(values);


    ClearCellRegistroMovimientos();
```

Comment: Hello! I don't quite get what are you trying to accomplish. If you want, you can also write here as a comment a brief explanation in Spanish too

Comment: Maybe also attach some sample spreadsheet ;)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: As far as I understand your code, you want to transfer to the dataS sheet ("REGISTRO STOCK") not all values from the C15:G17 range from the formS sheet ("Registro de Movimientos"), but only those where there are no empty cells (at least one cell filled)? Yes, it can be done. But why? Don't be shy, transfer everything, and before processing the data in "REGISTRO STOCK" just remove unnecessary rows using FILTER() or QUERY()

Answer (score 0):

Do you know this?

[image: Empty Value]

This means that after you have formed the next `var values = []`, you can concatenate 5, 6, 7, 8 and 9 elements and check if the result is an empty string. Not? Then do the recording. I hope you can write this `if(){}` yourself.